# Analytic extensions of convex-linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $S=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a set of vectors. Let us consider its convex and affine hulls:
$$
{\rm conv}(S)=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i \left\vert  \lambda_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1\right.\right\}
$$
and
$$
{\rm aff}(S)=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i \left\vert  \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1\right.\right\},
$$
respectively.

Consider a convex-linear function on $f:{\rm conv}(S)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$:
$$
f(w)=(1-\alpha)f(w_1)+\alpha f(w_2), \quad\text{with } 1\geq\alpha\geq0
$$
for $w=(1-\alpha)w_1+\alpha w_2$ and $w,w_1,w_2\in{\rm conv}(S)$.

The question is the following: Consider an extension $f^*$ of $f$ from ${\rm conv}(S)$ to ${\rm aff}(S)$:
\begin{eqnarray}
&f^*:{\rm aff}(S)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\\
&f^*(w)=f(w) \quad \text{for}\ w\in{\rm conv}(S).
\end{eqnarray}
If we require $f^*$ to be analytic (infinitely differentiable) on ${\rm aff}(S)$, must $f^*$ be affine?

Comment: Unless the question is missing some requirements, the answer appears to be trivially no; for example $f(x)=|x|$ is a non-affine function which is linear on the interval $[1,2]$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say "infinitely differentiable"

Comment: Okay; then let $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge 0$ and $\exp(1/x)$ for $x<0$. It's $C^\infty$ on the real line.

Comment: Ok, many thanks. I see there are many examples. I guess a similar one would be $f(x)=x$ for $x\geq0$ and $x\exp(x)$ for $x<0$.